# How to use a fetched access token (JSON) in the endpoint URI?

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0

How to refer to a fetched access token (JSON) in the endpoint URI in JavaScript?

Returned JSON Example

```
{token_type: 'Bearer', expires_at: 1681425284, expires_in: 15892, refresh_token: 'fetched_refresh_token94f5c1f7f241bnh11', access_token: 'fetched_access_token8c13694dd4b34c01f44b51', …}
```

JavaScript

```
async function getActivities(res) {
  const fetched_access_token = res.access_token;
  const activities_link = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/11111111?access_token=????what-to-put-here????`
```

I need the returned `access_token` to be referred in the endpoint URI to call the JSON data from the endpoint

Comment: `${fetched_access_token}`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76008023/how-to-use-a-fetched-access-token-to-fetch-an-endpoint)?

Comment: you should put the access token in the header, not in the URL. 
How access token implemented in API (how does it verify)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Comment: Related to previous my question indeed, but I still got an error there : "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: access_token is not defined." Apparently the token is not picked up because it is not global: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882561/referenceerror-token-is-not-defined
So, how do I make it global?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have everything in its place

```js
async function getActivities(res) {
  const fetched_access_token = res.access_token;
  const activities_link = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/11111111?access_token=${fetched_access_token}`
}
```

use the template strings `${}` notation to interpolate the string with the access token in the url

Comment: I still got the following error : "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: access_token is not defined." Apparently the token is not picked up because it is not global: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882561/referenceerror-token-is-not-defined 
So, how do I make it global here?

Comment: @user21633585 can you just console.log(res) to check whats inside it

Comment: {token_type: 'Bearer', expires_at: 1682001100, expires_in: 21600, refresh_token: 'dc5ce39b0031665a086a79e94f5c1f7f111c2dd0', access_token: '6df6da4381487a094b5a2811a0cf3072676e67ca', …}
exchange_token.asp?s…31f5d&scope=read:42 
 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: access_token is not defined
 at getActivities (exchange_token.asp?s…5d&scope=read:42:91)
 at exchange_token.asp?s…f5d&scope=read:34:5
getActivities @ exchange_token.asp?s…31f5d&scope=read:42
(anonymous) @ exchange_token.asp?s…31f5d&scope=read:34
Promise.then (async)  
(anonymous) @ exchange_token.asp?s…31f5d&scope=read:32

Comment: Sorry I couldn't quite follow, can you post a screenshot?